# Repeated refresh with firebase.on('value') listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from a Firebase real-time database and pass the object to a component in React as its state so that the component can automatically render when any changes are made to the database. The data that I retrieve is stored in the variable local_data and it is to be passed to the Full component.

However the page just constantly keeps refreshing when implemented this way. Instead I would like it to just show real time updates if any changes were made to the database.

The following are the relevant snippets of code (in Full.js this.state is passed to Charts):

index.js

```
var local_data = {}
window.location.reload();
ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login}/>
        <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register}/>
        <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404}/>
        <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500}/>
        <Route path="/original" name="Home" component={Full} sample={local_data}/>
        <Route path="/" name="Home" render={props => <Full local_data= {local_data} />} />
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Full.js

```
class Full extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  //Change this to be an object to iterate.
  console.log("In Full.js ->",props.local_data.greeting);
  this.state = {};
 }

componentWillMount(){
/* Create reference to messages in Firebase Database */
let db = firebase.database().ref('/');    
db.off();
db.on('value', snapshot => {
  /* Update React state when message is added at Firebase Database */
  let locData = snapshot.val();
  //this.setState(locData);
  this.state = locData;
})
}


render() {
 return (
  <div className="app">
    <Header />
    <div className="app-body">
      <Sidebar {...this.props}/>
      <main className="main">
        <Breadcrumb />
        <Container fluid>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route path="/components/buttons" name="Buttons" component={Buttons}/>
            <Route path="/components/cards" name="Cards" component={Cards}/>
            <Route path="/components/forms" name="Forms" component={Forms}/>
            <Route path="/components/modals" name="Modals" component={Modals}/>
            <Route path="/components/social-buttons" name="Social Buttons" component={SocialButtons}/>
            <Route path="/components/switches" name="Swithces" component={Switches}/>
            <Route path="/components/tables" name="Tables" component={Tables}/>
            <Route path="/components/tabs" name="Tabs" component={Tabs}/>
            <Route path="/icons/font-awesome" name="Font Awesome" component={FontAwesome}/>
            <Route path="/icons/simple-line-icons" name="Simple Line Icons" component={SimpleLineIcons}/>
            <Route path="/widgets" name="Widgets" component={Widgets}/>
            <Route path="/charts_original" name="Charts" component={Charts} />
            <Route path="/charts" name="Charts" render={props => <Charts local_data={this.state} {...props} />} />

            <Redirect from="/" to="/dashboard"/>
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Aside />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Full;
```

Comment: Are you using React Router? Which version? If 4.x be aware that not using "exact" in Route config, each component matched will be rendered.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool

Answer (score 0):

Use `db.on('value', snap => this.setState(snap.val()))` in your Full.js's componentDidMount. React doesn't like you mutating state directly https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

Comment: Given that it's a network request, and it might take a little while, you might also want to go with `local_data={this.state && this.state}` in your /charts route render prop.